# Format date stored as object as "mm dd yy" using format function in VBA

Tags: vba, date, format

For some reason my object "FDFormat" is storing the date as "4/2/18" even though I have it formatted to store it as "04 02 18". All the other objects are storing the date in the correct format. I am a bit confused as to why the others work fine, but "FDFormat" is having issues. Here is my code:

```
Dim FileYear, FileMonth, FileDate, FDFormat As Date
FileDate = #4/2/2018#
FDFormat = Format(FileDate, "mm dd yy") ' FDFormat = 4/2/18
FileYear = Year(FileDate) ' FileYear = 2018
FileMonth = Format(FileDate, "mmmm") ' FileMonth = "April"
```

Currently "FileDate" and "FDFormat" are the same. I am sure there is a simple explanation as I am not familiar with using the "format" function. The purpose of the code is for a user to be prompted to update the "FileDate" and then based on that the sub will open/save/close files based on the named objects. I am looking for a simple solution that doesn't involve the "len" function, a workaround, or "dim"ing any other objects. I want to understand why the "format" function is not working. Thanks!

Comment: declare FDFormat as string not date.  date has no formatting as it is a number displayed how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Below I have changed the file types in your `Dim` statement to reflect how you're intending the data to be stored:

```
Dim FileYear as Integer
Dim FileMonth as String
Dim FileDate as Date
Dim FDFormat As String
```

This is based on your code:

- `#4/2/2018#` ← represents a `Date` type (the actual value stored is `43192`)
- `Format(FileDate, "mm dd yy")` ← the `Format` function *always* returns a String
- `Year(FileDate)` ← the `Year` function returns an Integer
- `Format(FileDate, "mmmm")` ← the `Format` function *always* returns a String